# How to make div text appear line by line instead of all at once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, watson-assistant

I'm using IBM's Watson and right now my text is split by `<br> <br>` with any number of spaces between `<br>'s`. I tried splitting my JSON text at the `<br>'s` and mapping with a slight delay, but it doesn't really work. I've also tried opacity and display fiddling. [Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ELWxeB) of how the code that builds the HTML DOM message elements works. Each payload gets put into a div and displayed all at once.

I need each line split at the `<br> <br>` to appear shortly after the previous one, like an instant message effect. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried setTimeout with appendChild in the callback?

Answer (score 2):

Try this, you may need to improve the regular expression to take into account browser differences...etc:

```js
const target = document.getElementById('target');
const newInnerHTML = target.innerHTML
  .split(/<br>\s*/i)
  .map((text, i) => '<p style="animation-delay:' + (400 * i) + 'ms">' + text + '</p>')
  .join(''); 

target.innerHTML = newInnerHTML;
```

```css
#target p {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade-in 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target"> Hi, I'm Watson. <br> <br> I need to appear line by line.
</div>
```